# Как вернуть таблицу с некоторыми объединенными строками в SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица (пусть ее имя schedule) вида:

```
[id][hour][minutes]  
[1 ][6   ][35     ]
[2 ][7   ][15     ]
[3 ][7   ][35     ]
[4 ][8   ][10     ]
[5 ][9   ][50     ]
[6 ][9   ][55     ]
```

Мне нужно объединить те строки в которых совпадает столбец hour.
Какой запрос нужно выполнить к данной таблице чтобы получить такой результат?:

```
[id][hour][minutes]  
[1 ][6   ][35     ]
[2 ][7   ][15 35  ]
[3 ][8   ][10     ]
[4 ][9   ][50 55  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, hour, GROUP_CONCAT(munites, " ") 
    FROM table 
    GROUP_BY(hour)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!